# Minimum value made of the reciprocals of the first $n$ primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, primorial

Let $n$ be a positive integer , $p_k$ the k-th prime number and $a_j=-1$ or $a_j=1$ for $j=1,\cdots ,n$

> What is the minimum value of $$S:=|\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{a_j}{p_j}|$$ ?

Motivation : If we multiply such a number with the product of the first $n$ primes (which is $p_n$# , let us call it $P$) , then $S\cdot P$ is divisible by no prime factor upto the n-th prime number since every summand except one is divisible by a particular prime number among the first $n$ primes. Therefore, if we can make $S\cdot P$ small , the chance for a prime number is good.

Aditionally : Can we prove that $S\cdot P=1$ is impossible for $n>3$ ?

For $4\le n\le 25$ , $S\cdot P=1$ is impossible. The smallest values for $S\cdot P$ , when $1$ is excluded , are summarized in a table using PARI/GP :

```
gp > for(k=2,25,p=prod(j=1,k,prime(j));mini=10^1000;forvec(z=vector(k,j,[0,1]),a=vector(length(z),j,2*z[j]-1);s=abs(sum(j=1,length(z),a[j]/prime(j)));n=s*p;if(n>1,if(n<mini,mini=n;merk1=a;merk2=s*p)));print(k,"  ",merk1,"   ",merk2,"   ",isprime(merk2,3)))
2  [-1, -1]   5   1
3  [-1, 1, -1]   11   1
4  [-1, 1, 1, -1]   23   1
5  [-1, 1, 1, -1, 1]   43   1
6  [-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1]   251   1
7  [-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1]   263   1
8  [-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1]   21013   1
9  [-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1]   1407079   0
10  [-1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]   4919311   0
11  [-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1]   818778281   0
12  [-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1]   2402234557   0
13  [-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1]   379757743297   0
14  [-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1]   3325743954311   0
15  [-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1]   54237719914087   0
16  [-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1]   903944329576111   0
17  [-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1]   46919460458733911   0
18  [-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1]   367421942920402841   0
19  [-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]   17148430651130576323   0
20  [-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1]   1236225057834436760243   0
21  [-1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1]   4190310920096832376289   0
22  [-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1]   535482916756698482410061   0
23  [-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1]   29119155169912957197310753   0
24  [-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1]   443284248908491516288671253    0
25  [-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1]   28438781483496930396689638231   0
gp >
```

Unfortunately, for $9\le n\le 25$, the minimum value is not prime. Perhaps, the minimum value still grows too fast with $n$.

An extension of the table or an estimate of the minimum value and the chance to find a prime would be very appreciated.

Comment: I suspect it has infimum zero. It's just a matter of proving this.

Comment: @AdamRubinson It's easy to show that the smallest possible value for $S$ is at most $\frac1{p_n}$, by induction on $n$.

Comment: @Mastrem yes. Doesn't that answer OP's question then? ...

Comment: @AdamRubinson No, because in reality we can do much better and he asks for the minimal value. In fact, if we allow zeroes too, beside $\pm 1$, I think it can be shown we can get something of order of magnitude $\frac{\log n}{2^n}$. And to answer the second question, we'd need a lower bound on the minimal value, not an upper bound.

Comment: @Mastrem but OP's question is not, "what is the best rate of convergence towards $0$ possible?" . His question, as written, is "Can we choose the $a_j$ so that the series converges towards zero?", to which the answer is yes. I take his question to be what is written in the blockquote. Everything he has written after is secondary. But maybe he will reply to this in the comments. I'm going to wait and see.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I thought it is clear that I am looking for the minimum depending on $n$. In particular, a lower bound for the minimum would be great that rules out $S\cdot P=1$ for $n>3$ , but also to be able to judge the probability that some minima of $S\cdot P$ for $n>25$ are prime numbers.

Comment: Ah, ok then. Fair enough.

Comment: Note that $SP=1$ implies $P\equiv \pm p_i\pmod{p_i^2}$ for all $1\le i\le n$. This can probably be turned into a heuristic arugment that $SP\neq 1$ for $n> 3$ is impossible. Naively, the probability of this happening for $p_i\ge 3$ is $\frac{2}{p_i-1}$, so the probability of it happening for all primes up to $p_n$ is $\frac{2^{n-1}}{\phi(P)}$, assuming (among other things) independence. The 'expected value' sum $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{2^{n-1}}{\phi(P_n)}$ converges, so you'd expect it to happen only finitely many times.