# If we can't change the order of the terms of a conditionally convergent series, but can change the sign of terms, can we get whatever number we want?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, conditional-convergence

> Let $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} x_n\ $ be a [conditionally
> convergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence), and we can choose $\ a_j=-1\ $ or $\ a_j=1\ $
> for each $j\in\mathbb{N}.$
>
> Let $\ \beta\in\mathbb{R}.$
>
> Can we choose the $\ a_j\ $ so that
>
> $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n x_n = \beta\quad ? $$

If so, we can solve [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4333412/minimum-value-made-of-the-reciprocals-of-the-first-n-primes) I came across this morning by letting $\ x_n = \left(-1\right)^n\frac{1}{p_n},\ $ where $\ p_n\ $ is the $\ n-$th prime number, because this is a conditionally convergent series. Edit: this is not what the question was asking.

Note that my question is different to the [Riemann Series Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem), which says that we can keep the terms, but rearrange the order. In my question we are *changing the terms*.

Comment: This works as follows : Given a real number $r$, choose "+" until the sum is greater than $r$ , then "-" until the sum is smaller than $r$ and continue this way forever. The series will then converge to $r$.

Comment: @Peter yes that seems obvious. But how to prove it formally?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Try to prove that the partial sums $S_n$ eventually satisfy $|S_n - X| \le \max_{j \ge n} |x_j|$, where $X$ is the target value. Clearly this will imply convergence.

Comment: Maybe I should try to understand Riemann Series theorem first...

Comment: No. Ok I get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proof outline**

$\sum x_n\ $ is conditionally convergent implies:

$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} x_n =\gamma\in\mathbb{R}\qquad (1)$$

$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \vert x_n \vert = \infty \qquad (2)$$

$$\ \vert x_n \vert \to 0^+\qquad (3)$$

$(1)\implies\ $ there exists $\ N\in\mathbb{N}\ $ such that $\ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i\ $ is very close to $\ \gamma\ $ for all $\ k\geq N.$

Next, we can use $\ (2)\ $ and $\ (3)\ $ to get from $\ \gamma\ $ to very close to $\ \beta.$